# How does one create a pandas column (binary) based on whether or not another column contains dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am analyzing customer churn. My dataset contains years of customers that have stayed or left. I need to create a ['CHURN_FLAG'] column based on whether or not there is a date in the ['CHURN_DATE'] column. If there is a date in the ['CHURN_DATE'] column then the customer churned.

Current data frame:

| CHURNdate |
| --- |
| 2023-1-1 |
| NaT |

Desired:

| CHURNdate | CHURNflag |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-1-1 | 1 |
| NaT | 0 |

I created a column ['TODAY_DATE'] and have attempted to solve by assessing if the ['CHURNdate'] < ['TODAY_DATE'] then the binary 1 would populate, else 0. Here is the code:

```
df2['CHURNflag'] = np.where(df2['CHURNdate']<df2['TODAY_DATE'], 0, 1)
```

Naturally, it didn't work. :( The datatypes are datetime64

Comment: Since `NaT` is a NaN type, you can use [isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) to get a boolean of whether it's a dat or NaT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
churn['CHURNflag'] = np.where(churn['CHURNdate'].isna(), 0, 1)

Out[24]: 
    CHURNdate  CHURNflag
0  2023-01-01          1
1         NaN          0
```

Comment: This can be simplified further by casting the boolean directly to int: `churn['CHURNflag']=churn['CHURNdate'].isna().astype(int)`